# How to make mutiple lines in R

Tags: r, dataframe, newline

I have the data like this, I want to draw multiple lines in R, the lines contained `SC1`, `SC2`, `SC3`, `SC4` and `SC5`, the `xlab` is `chr` (from 1 to 10).

```
              chr      pos          SC1          SC2          SC3          SC4           SC5
chr01.8.5      1    0.000  2.420907e-02 1.317053e+00 7.171021e-02 3.280758e-03   1.185807e+00
chr01.6.5      1    0.714   0.040931607 1.150449274   0.042270667  0.044192568    0.976696855
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and slightly dirty way is to use `?matlines`

```
# assume d is your data
plot(d$chr, d$pos)            # plots the data as points
matlines(d$chr, d[,-(1:2)])     # plots every column except 1,2 against d$chr
```

Comment: `-1:2` is equivalent to `c(-1,0,1,2)` which will error out. Using `-(1:2)` is fine though.